# Lock orientation but still detect orientation changes

Tags: react-native

I have locked orientation on small devices using layout like so:

`const layout = {orientation: ['portrait']}`

However, I'd still like to detect attempts at orientation change. The typical way to detect changes in RN is `Dimensions.addEventListener('change', handleOrientationChange)`. Since this is locked, though, dimensions change event never happens. Is there some other way to detect attempts at changing orientation from RN when locked?